# jQuery php variable echo not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a little contact form, where I would like to ask the user to calculate and enter the correct value in order to prevent spam. Now, when the send button is clicked, I fire a php script, where I change the calculation values. I would like to echo these values and show them as the new placeholder in case of both, success, as well as failure.

```
$("#send_button").click(function() {

        var url = "contact.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#contact_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                   var txt = "<?php echo 'Spam protection: Calculate ($first_num + $second_num) x $multiplier';?>";
                   $("#form_info_label").css('color','#0ed68d');                                   
                   $("#form_info_label").text(data);
                   $("#user_answer").attr("placeholder",txt);

               },
               error: function(data) { 

                   var txt = "<?php echo 'Spam protection: Calculate ($first_num + $second_num) x $multiplier';?>";
                   alert(txt);
                   $("#form_info_label").css('color','#f2275e');
                   $("#form_info_label").text("Error. Please try again.");
                   $("#user_answer").removeAttr('value');
                   $("#user_answer").attr("placeholder",txt);

               }  

             });

        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
```

However my placeholder ends up not interpreting it as php code, but just simply copies the text. So my placeholder then ends up displaying:

```
<?php echo 'Spam protection: Calculate ($first_num + $second_num) x $multiplier';?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up returning a json-encoded array with my desired values from php back to javascript and parsed the response there.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need PHP tags

```
var txt = "<?php echo 'Spam protection: Calculate ($first_num + $second_num) x $multiplier'; ?>";
```

You actually have it right in the error handler, so you probably just forgot, and now you've edited the question to include them ?

If you have PHP tags, and it's still not being parsed, the file the javascript is in is not being parsed by PHP.

Comment: Nope, sorry, my mistake, that was just a test case. I actually use the error handler to test.

Comment: If the PHP tags are outputted, the file is not parsed by PHP, that's the only possible explanation for that.

Comment: Okay, and what can I do about that ?

Comment: What sort of file is it? A .js file!

Comment: this won't work... you also need quotes around the string parts

Comment: .js files are not parsed by PHP, and generally they shouldn't be. Add the PHP code to the PHP file the javascript is included in and get the result from that file with javascript. You can change the .htaccess file to make PHP parse .js files, but that's generally a bad idea.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans - If the PHP tags are outputted, it doesn't matter where you add quotes, it still won't work.

Comment: If you echo that line out in a javascript variable in your PHP page, and make that variable global etc. you can just use it in the javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

Remember on comuputers to use the * for multiply things, not the x.

And it´s also not clear, what your function "Calculate($param)" does, but usally you don´t need a function for adding one variable to another. But the brackets still needed...

Comment: I don't think it's a function, but a question to the user to calculate two values given in the variables, as a sort of "check if human" question.

Comment: As in -> `Spam protection: Calculate (3 + 2) x 2`

Comment: Yes adeneo is correct... It is what the user will be faced with. There is absolutely no php in the echo but the variables.

Comment: but why then you use the $ sign to indicate php that´s a variable? Variable resolving only works with double quotes or with the <<<

Answer (score 0):

In my case the PHP tag was not interpreted by js either. A solution I found was:

In my php file I defined the variable in a non-visible div:

```
?>
<div id="first_num" style="display: none">
    <?php echo $first_num; ?>
    </div>
<?php
```

In the jquery file I read the div value like this:

```
var first_num= $("#first_num").text().trim();
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all what adeneo already said: .js files are not parsed by PHP.

Secondly PHP variables will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

You should use either double quotes or

```
echo 'Spam protection: Calculate ('.$first_num.' + '.$second_num.') x '.$multiplier;
```